# Gnuplot - grid at specific x and y points

Tags: gnuplot, grid-layout

I wanted to rename xtics from numbers to some strings and I did it like this:

```
set xtics ("one" 1, "two" 2, ...)
```

At the same time I wanted the grid so I used this:

```
set grid back
```

The problem now is that the grid is made so its vertical lines are at 1, 2, etc. Is it
possible to make grid where vertical lines are at arbitrary/different places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the grid to only be drawn where there are minor ticks.  Then you can explicitly set the minor ticks the same way you set the major ticks:

```
set xtics ( "one" 1, "two" 2, "" 3 1 )
#           ^major   ^major   ^minor tick because the "level" is set to 1.
set grid mxtics
plot sin(x)
```

You can also make it so that the mxtics don't show up:

```
set xtics scale 1,0
```